# What is the purpose of AbstractSystem trait in akka-spray-websocket activator?

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I'm learning Spray and Akka. And I'm learning it through TypeSafe's templates, and this one is very complex at least:

http://typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-spray-websocket

I now understand the werid structure this template has is to separate routing logic and business logic and it's amazingly done. However, although I know the purpose of this structure, I don't know what's the functionality of this small piece and why is it necessary:

They have a class called [MainActors.scala](https://github.com/cuali/SprayEasterEggs/blob/master/src/main/scala/reactive/api/MainActors.scala):

```
trait MainActors {
  this: AbstractSystem =>

  lazy val find = system.actorOf(Props[FindActor], "find")
  lazy val hide = system.actorOf(Props[HideActor], "hide")
}
```

Then the template concatenates all the routings under a class called [ReactiveApi.scala](https://github.com/cuali/SprayEasterEggs/blob/master/src/main/scala/reactive/api/ReactiveApi.scala):

```
trait AbstractSystem {
  implicit def system: ActorSystem
}

trait ReactiveApi extends RouteConcatenation with StaticRoute with AbstractSystem {
  this: MainActors =>

  val rootService = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[RootService], routes))

  lazy val routes = logRequest(showReq _) {
    new FindService(find).route ~
    new HideService(hide).route ~
    staticRoute
  }

  private def showReq(req : HttpRequest) = LogEntry(req.uri, InfoLevel)
}
```

Actually, my question is simple: what is the purpose of `AbstractSystem` trait? how is it used and why is it used?

This trait is also passed into actual actor:

```
class FindService(find : ActorRef)(implicit system : ActorSystem) extends Directives {
  lazy val route = ...
}
```

Also, if it is not entirely inconvenient, what's the functionality of `logRequest()` and `showReq()`?

For Spray: why do I have to pass an actor (`ActorRef`) into `FindServce`? I don't see any specific methods being invoked from inside.

Comment: I guess it's there to make an implicit `ActorSystem` value available inside the `ReactiveApi` trait without having to specify the exact value at this point. In some way, it's a workaround for Scala not supporting implicit parameters on traits (e.g. compared to the `FindService` class).

Comment: @jrudolph I agree! But how do you explain `this: AbstractSystem =>` in the MainActor class?

Comment: it is [explicit typed self reference](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/explicitly-typed-self-references.html). By typing this you assure compiler that this trait will be always extended with `Abstract System`. It gives you access to methods and fields from `Abstract System` inside of the trait `Main Actors`. In `ReactiveAPI` trait you see that we access fields `find` and `hide`. We can do this because `ReactiveAPI` is self referencing `MainActors`. In the same time `ReactiveAPI` extends `AbstractSystem` just like we assured compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple example of using `abstract def`s in order to do the [cake pattern](http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/) (very simplified though). The goal is to say "hey, I need this thing", and the implementor must then provide the actor system to you – by implementing the `def system`. The goal is of course to make this def available to `MainActors`.

As for the self type reference, you can refer to [ktoso/types-of-types#self-type-annotation](http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/#self-type-annotation) to find out more about it.